# Convert GeoJSON polygon to point before rendering in Leaflet Map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, json

I have a GeoJSON dataset which has points and polygons. I have a simple Leaflet code which reads them into a map, like this:

```
var MyLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/UrbanSyntax/Desarrollo/twitter/data/boxtest.json", {

pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {      
return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
  radius: 3,
  fillOpacity: 0.75,
  color: getColor(feature.properties.created_at)
});
},
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
layer.bindPopup(
feature.properties.created_at + '<br />'
+ feature.geometry.coordinates + '<br />'
+ feature.properties.user  )
}
});
```

Most of the data are polygons, but I need to translate them to points (the polygon center) to simplify the map. I don't want to change the original GeoJSON when it's parsed since those polygons might be needed later.

I don't know where to "inject" code to read the polygon bounds, calculate a center and send a latlng to make a circlemarker. As it is now, the code reads the points and polygons in the json ok, but there are too many polygons in the data so the browser freezes. It works all right when I filter out the polys from the JSON and just map the points. I'm running out of ideas, and Leaflet documentation is so scarce in the JSON chapter... I just need a way to put an if in the pointToLayer code, separate the points from the polys, and map them all as points.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Cross-posted on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41664266/6680611).

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) to calculate the [centroids](http://turfjs.org/docs/#centroid) of the polygons.

Just include it in your HTML head. In my case, I am using the CDN:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@3.5.2/turf.min.js"></script>
```

In the following code I am using *onEachFeature* to check whether the current feature is a polygon, since it would not make sense to convert points. If it is a polygon I am using Turf to calculate its centroid, which gives me a *lat* and *lon*, which can be used to add a new marker.

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(MyLayer,{
                    onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                        if (feature.geometry.type === 'Polygon') {
                            console.log('Polygon detected');
                            var centroid = turf.centroid(feature);
                            var lon = centroid.geometry.coordinates[0];
                            var lat = centroid.geometry.coordinates[1];
                            L.marker([lat,lon]).addTo(map);
                        }
                }
            });

geojson.addTo(map);
```

I have tested this with a GeoJSON including points and polyons.
The original dataset looks like this:

[image]

When the above code is executed then you see that the points remain points and the polygons are transformed to centroids, without ever changing the original dataset.

[image]

Of course you would not show both, I just did it to show that the example works! You would only show the points.

You can use this with *L.CircleMarker* as well, I just used *L.marker*, because it was a quicker way to demonstrate how this works. I also omitted your popup to shorten the code, but it looks like you will not even have to change it.

Comment: Thank you! That's an awesome pointer for me, gjson utils looks kinda abandoned.

Comment: very nice, exactly what i was looking for also. Thank you